# nodejs + python celery: InvalidTaskError: Task keyword arguments must be a mapping

Tags: python, node.js, rabbitmq, celery

I have a python celery app that acts as a client, with a task to scrap movies, connected to rabbitmq server.
On the other hand, a nodeJS backend which will be responsible for receiving HTTP requests and calling the scraping task (queueing the task using amqplib).

celery app file is as follows:

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery('scraper', broker='amqps://')

@app.task(serializer='json')
def scrapNewMovies(url, limit):
    print("Recieved")
    return True
```

nodejs app file is as follows:

```
const {delayScrapNewMovies} = require('./celery/tasks');
const express = require("express");
const app = express()

app.get("", async (req, res)=> {

  try{
    await delayScrapNewMovies()

    return res.json({"Hello":"There"})
  } catch( err ){
    console.log(err)
  }
})


app.listen(8000)
```

nodejs delay task function:

```
const amqp = require('amqplib');

async function delayScrapNewMovies() {

  const connection = await amqp.connect('amqps://');
  const channel = await connection.createChannel();
  const queueName = 'celery';
  const headers = {
    'task': 'app.celery.scrapNewMovies',
    'id': '123',
  }

  const properties = {
    'correlation_id':'123',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'content-encoding': 'utf-8',
  }
  const message = {
    task: 'app.celery.scrapNewMovies',
    args: [],
    kwargs: {
      "url": "https://example.com/movies",
      "limit": 10
    },
    id: '123',
  };



  await channel.assertQueue(queueName);
  channel.sendToQueue(queueName, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(message)),{ headers:headers, properties:properties });

}
  
module.exports = {delayScrapNewMovies}
```

Now everything is working fine, celery and node are running perfectly, but whenever i hit a request to call the `delayScrapNewMovies`, i get the following error from celery 'worker logs':

```
Received invalid task message: Task keyword arguments must be a mapping
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Please ensure your message conforms to the task
message protocol as described here:
http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html

The full contents of the message body was:
b'{"task":"app.celery.scrapNewMovies","args":[],"kwargs":{"url":"https://example.com/movies","limit":10},"id":"123"}' (114b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/strategy.py", line 29, in hybrid_to_proto2
    args, kwargs = body.get('args', ()), body.get('kwargs', {})
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 596, in on_task_received
    strategy(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/strategy.py", line 141, in task_message_handler
    body, headers, decoded, utc = hybrid_to_proto2(message,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/strategy.py", line 34, in hybrid_to_proto2
    raise InvalidTaskError(
celery.exceptions.InvalidTaskError: Task keyword arguments must be a mapping
```

Apparently, the problem has to do with the format of the message sent to the queue. I tried to send it in many different formats, i also tried to use different celery serializers, but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved**

As expected, message format was incorrect, and content type/encoding needed to be specified in the options field, and also using publish method instead of sendQueue.

delay function should be as follows:

```
async function delayScrapNewMovies() {

  const connection = await amqp.connect('amqps://');
  const channel = await connection.createChannel();
  const queueName = 'celery';

  const headers = {
    'task': 'app.celery.scrapNewMovies',
    'id': '123',
    "lang": "py",
    "argsrepr": '',
    "kwargsrepr": "{}"
  }

  const body = {
    args: [],
    kwargs:{"url": "https://example.com/movies","limit": 10}
  }

  const options = {
    headers:headers, 
    contentType:'application/json', 
    contentEncoding:'utf-8',
    deliveryMode: 2

  }
  await channel.assertQueue(queueName);
  channel.publish("",queueName, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(body)), options);

}
```